# r bquote: remove the space before approximately equal plotmath symbol

Tags: r, plotmath

This is almost what I want as a plot heading:

```
plot(1:10)
ylabs<-c("All","Native","Exotic")
i=1
mtext(bquote("("*.(letters[i])*")"~.(ylabs[i])~"("%~~%italic("H'")*")"),side=3)
```

But I don't want the space after "(" and before the approx. equal sign. Adding the * separator before the symbol gives an error

```
mtext(bquote("("*.(letters[i])*")"~.(ylabs[i])~"("*%~~%italic("H'")*")"),side=3)
```

> Error: unexpected SPECIAL in

even though the * separator works in other parts of bquote. I can get the right spacing by including the approx. equal symbol directly

```
mtext(bquote("("*.(letters[i])*")"~.(ylabs[i])~"("*"≈"~italic("H'")*")"),side=3)
```

but I would like to know if there's a way to get * to work before the plotmath symbol?

I tried this with expression instead of bquote, but couldn't get it to combine the characters with the indexed objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to put the entire text into a subscript:

```
plot(1:10)
ylabs<-c("All","Native","Exotic")
i=1
b <- bquote(phantom(0)["("*.(letters[i])*")"~.(ylabs[i])~"(" %~~%italic("H'")*")"])
mtext(b, cex = 2, side=3)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I will read up on phantom as I don't understand the logic yet, but it works, so thank you.

Comment: It's just a placeholder.  An empty string would work just as well: `""` (two quotes in a row).