# Remove space between symbol and text when using 'expression'

Tags: r

I want to use the function 'expression' in r to be able to add symbols as '≤'
Example:

```
plot(1:10,1:10)
legend(3,8, c(expression(""<="test ")))
```

With this code there will be a space between ≤ and test, I want there to be no space: ≤test, how to accomplish this?
Thanks[image]

Comment: does trick from here suit your needs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43696101/r-bquote-remove-the-space-before-approximately-equal-plotmath-symbol e.g.`legend(3,5, ~phantom('')[''<= "test "], cex=3)`; suspect with multiple legend items this will take a bit of faffing about with placement / size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use unicode symbols (`\U2264` for `≤`) and do it without the expression?

```r
plot(1:10,1:10)
legend(3,8, "\U2264test") # legend(3,8, "≤test")
```

[image]

Comment: it doesnt work for me, see my response to the question, and an attached picture!

Comment: it works, thanks a lot! How to know this?! IS there a list of codes somewhere which is good to know about? How would it be for ≥?

Comment: Se e.g. https://www.classe.cornell.edu/~dms79/LectureNotes/formulae/list-of-math-symbols-extended.htm